# How to build a Neural Network with sentence embeding concatenated to pre-trained CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

I want to build a neural network that will take the feature map from the last layer of a CNN (VGG or resnet for example), concatenate an additional vector (for example , 1X768 bert vector) , and re-train the last layer on classification problem.
So the architecture should be like in:
[image]

but I want to concat an additional vector to each feature vector (I have a sentence to describe each frame).

I have 5 possible labels , and 100 frames in the input frames.

Can someone help me as to how to implement this type of network?

Comment: @okuoub Unfortunately, this sounds like an assignment, homework or work-related project with no attempt from your side to show any effort to solve it. I might be wrong about the nature of the project but at the very least please show us what you already know and have done with your code and tell us specifically where you are exactly struggling with or don't understand. Then we will be able to help you better. Thank you! (note that this site is not a tutorial or teaching site to teach you how to implement an entire project from 0 to 100. Instead, we are here to resolve concrete struggles).

Comment: ^ Yeah, give the code sample of how you are currently handling the frames, so that people can jump in and suggest where the *concat* would make sense!

Comment: @today please see the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63809805/build-pre-trainedcnnlstm-network-with-keras-functional-api

Comment: @ParthaMandal I added my efforts in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63809805/build-pre-trainedcnnlstm-network-with-keras-functional-api

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into the **Keras functional API**.

Unlike a sequential model (which is usually enough for many introductory problems), the *functional API* allows you to create any acyclic graph you want. This means that you can have *two* input branches, one for the CNN (image data) and the other for any NLP you need to do (relating to the descriptive sentence that you mentioned). Then, you can feed in the combined outputs of these two branches into the final layers of your network and produce your result.

Even if you've already created your model using `models.Sequential()`, it shouldn't be too hard to rewrite it to use the functional API.

**For more information and implementation details, look at the official documentation here: https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/**