# Build (pre-trained) CNN+LSTM network with keras functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I want to build an LSTM on top of pre-trained CNN (VGG) to classify a video sequence. The LSTM will be fed with the features extracted by the last FC layer of VGG.

The architecture is something like:

[image]

I wrote the code:

```
def build_LSTM_CNN_net()
      from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
      from keras.models import Model
      from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Flatten
      from keras.layers.pooling import GlobalAveragePooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling1D
      from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
      from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed
      from keras.optimizers import Nadam
    
    
      from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

      num_classes = 5
      frames = Input(shape=(5, 224, 224, 3))
      base_in = Input(shape=(224,224,3))
    
      base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(224,224,3))
    
      x = Flatten()(base_model.output)
      x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
      x = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(x)
      x = LSTM(units = 256, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.2)(x)
      x = Dense(self.nb_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    
lstm_cnn = build_LSTM_CNN_net()
keras.utils.plot_model(lstm_cnn, "lstm_cnn.png", show_shapes=True)
```

But got the error:

```
ValueError: `TimeDistributed` Layer should be passed an `input_shape ` with at least 3 dimensions, received: [None, 128]
```

Why is this happening, how can I fix it?

Comment: You see?! You got an answer in less than an hour! That's the difference between a good question with enough details vs. asking the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63547650/2099607) without showing any efforts or providing any details; and even further, offering bounties won't help to get an answer for a poorly-asked question. Good luck and have fun :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here the correct way to build a model to classify video sequences. Note that I wrap into TimeDistributed a model instance. This model was previously build to extract features from each frame individually. In the second part, we deal the frame sequences

```
frames, channels, rows, columns = 5,3,224,224

video = Input(shape=(frames,
                     rows,
                     columns,
                     channels))
cnn_base = VGG16(input_shape=(rows,
                              columns,
                              channels),
                 weights="imagenet",
                 include_top=False)
cnn_base.trainable = False

cnn_out = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(cnn_base.output)
cnn = Model(cnn_base.input, cnn_out)
encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(cnn)(video)
encoded_sequence = LSTM(256)(encoded_frames)
hidden_layer = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(encoded_sequence)
outputs = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(hidden_layer)

model = Model(video, outputs)
model.summary()
```

if you want to use the VGG 1x4096 emb representation you can simply do:

```
frames, channels, rows, columns = 5,3,224,224

video = Input(shape=(frames,
                     rows,
                     columns,
                     channels))
cnn_base = VGG16(input_shape=(rows,
                              columns,
                              channels),
                 weights="imagenet",
                 include_top=True) #<=== include_top=True
cnn_base.trainable = False

cnn = Model(cnn_base.input, cnn_base.layers[-3].output) # -3 is the 4096 layer
encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(cnn)(video)
encoded_sequence = LSTM(256)(encoded_frames)
hidden_layer = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(encoded_sequence)
outputs = Dense(10, activation="softmax")(hidden_layer)

model = Model(video, outputs)
model.summary()
```